# Referrer is lost when user clicks on prerendered link before angular loads

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager, angular-universal, referrer

For seo and performance reasons we are serving a prerendered version of our site ([angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)). So if the user reaches our site via google, the prerendered page will load - at that moment the referrer is google.com. If the user then clicks a link ([routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)) on the site before angular is fully loaded the original referrer will be lost/replaced (which will show up as direct traffic). For tracking we use [Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide).

Weirdly enough I haven't found anyone having a similar problem (google/stackoverflow).

To test solutions to the problem I recreated it with the [starter setup for angular universal from angular.io](https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip). The template of the app-component only needs to include the link (routerLink) to the lazy loaded route. And I added the standard google tag manager script on the index.html.

To test a probable solution in chrome I:

1. clear the cache
2. go to google.com
3. place an 'a href' to my locally running server in the html via dev-tools
4. disable cache
5. set throttling to slow 3G
6. start recording tracking via the 'Google Tag Assistent'-Chrome extension
7. click the link to localhost on the manipulated google.com-site
8. wait for the prerendered site to show
9. click the link that routes to the lazy routed module shorty after it becomes visible
10. wait for the site to fully load
11. stop recording in the 'Google Tag Assistent'-Chrome extension
12. open show full report in the 'Google Tag Assistent'-Chrome extension

Adding [preboot](https://github.com/angular/preboot) was my initial go to solution but sadly it had no effect.

Setting the referrer via google analytics (`ga('set', 'referrer', 'http://example.com');`) had no effect on the tracking with Google Tag Manager.

The referrer field in the document is readonly, but even if you work around it - that is not getting picked up by tracking:

```
        Object.defineProperty(document, 'referrer', {
          get: function() {
            'http://example.com';
          },
        });
```

I tried submitting the referrer together with pushing events to gtm - for example like this:

```
      window[layerName].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js',
        referrer: 'http://example.com',
      });
```

Or this:

```
      window[layerName].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js',
        f: 'http://example.com',
      });
```

Relevant code to reproduce (replaced the GTM-Tag/Id):

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ng Universal Demo - GTM</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
          'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
          event: 'gtm.js',
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayerNew', 'GTM-123456');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      try {
        console.log('index.html -> document.referrer', document['referrer']);
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('Could not get referrer from document', { error });
      }

      window.document.addEventListener('PrebootComplete', () => {
        console.log('PrebootComplete');
      });
    </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
      <iframe
        src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W476HVK"
        height="0"
        width="0"
        style="display:none;visibility:hidden"
      ></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TransferHttpCacheModule } from '@nguniversal/common';

import { PrebootModule } from 'preboot';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'my-app' }),
    PrebootModule.withConfig({ appRoot: 'app-root' }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
      { path: 'lazy/nested', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
    ]),
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Solution-attempts tested with both prerendering and server side rendering.

If it would be working as expected there would be only one page tracked ('Google Tag Assistent'-Chrome extension) with the correct initial referrer and all tags would be attached to that one page.

Any hints / leads / tips are well appreciated!

Comment: No idea about your actual problem, but if you want to change attribution for GA you'd have to go to your GA tag in GTM and set the campaignMedium and campaignSource fields to "referrer" and "google" respectively.

Comment: @hannes, I think this is a rogue referral problem. Take a look at this blog by Simo Ahava. https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/